# Proper asset disposal with LibGdx AssetManager

Tags: libgdx, assets

I am building a game that contains several mini-games. Each mini-game has it's own screen.

Right now I am loading all assets when starting the application instead of specific assets per every mini-game.

My question is, using the AssetManager, how would I best dispose of the assets when switching from one mini-game to another? `manager.dispose()` will not work, since that will dispose everything and it only gets loaded when the application is started.

Currently I am handeling it like this:

```
atlas = GdxAssetManager.manager.get(GdxAssetManager.runner, TextureAtlas.class);
```

Then when the mini-game is over and I go back to the menu I call this:

```
 public void dispose(){
        for(int i = 0; i < obstacles.size; i++){
            obstacles.get(i).dispose(); //unload the assets from each object in this array
        }
        GdxAssetManager.manager.unload(GdxAssetManager.runner); //unload the atlas in example code above
        scoreHandler.dispose(); //unloading object assets
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I was you I would create a method in your GdxAssetManager (I am guessing that it is custom made by youself) that helps pick which assets to load in which screen.

for example:

```
public void loadAssets(int screen) {

if(screen ==1)
//...Load assets
if(screen ==2)
//...Load different Assets

}
```

The same goes with dispose()

just do manager.clear()

This is a very good source to read: [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#disposing-assets)

Comment: I have thought about this approach, think it is the one I will go with, the more mini-games I add the more sense it makes to not load all assets on app-start

Comment: However, this does give the problem that you will dispose the Menu-screens assets aswell. which is probably not optimal

Comment: @WEDEBE Well you could don't use manager.clear() and use manager.unload whatever assets you loaded. Create a list of String and use those strings to record you file name